# Node.js TLS options for TLS-only connection negotiation

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I'd like for my node.js server to only accept either TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 connections, and I'm struggling a bit to find the correct SSL method which suits my case. Here's my current ciphers and SSL method:

```
ciphers          : "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH",
secureProtocol   : "SSLv23_server_method"
```

This results in these protocols according to ssllabs.com:

```
SSL 3: 0x35   TLS 1.0: 0x35
```

Any suggestions? I'm trying to achieve a fairly modern and secure SSL setup.

Comment: It could be a good idea to use Nginx as a proxy.

Comment: Although… have you tried `secureProtocol: "TLSv1_server_method"`?

Comment: So you're suggesting a reverse nginx proxy with `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;` basically?

Comment: Yep! Although `TLSv1_server_method` seems promising if you’ve already got everything else set up. Also, SSLv3 is really not that bad, and most clients won’t use it — why bother disallowing it?

Comment: `TLSv1_server_method` gives me just `TLS 1.0: 0x35` which is probably good enough for today as most browser don't even support v1.2. I wanted to disable SSLv3 to get a perfect score on SSLabs's test, and I'm not seeing why I should support deprecated protocols anyways.

Comment: Seems like [openssl's docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html) made it pretty clear now that I'd need more fine-grained control on how to set the supported protocols(through SSL_CTX_set_options() or SSL_set_options() which node.js doesn't expose), so I'm pretty sure I'd need some kind of proxy before node...

Comment: You can’t get a perfect score on the SSLabs test with SSLv3 disabled, it’ll dock you on protocol support. Link to the current one?

Comment: You can mitigate BEAST by using GCM ciphers instead of CBC (low support, not even in Chrome yet) or by using RC4 (which will now net you a bigger penalty on that test, because RC4 is not considered as secure and BEAST is mostly mitigated client-side now). Take a look at Google’s results for about the best practical score and security.

Comment: Thanks, I will. Luckily node supports this standardized cipher format, but still no [ECDHE](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4315) unfortunately. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

below is my suggestion for nginx ssl configuration, and which will make your ssl score A in ssllab.com ssl test, please try it.

```
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:100m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +RC4 RC4";
```

Comment: I'm already using something similar: https://gist.github.com/silverwind/4d417ee6710b6bd7fbb9, combined with a HSTS header this gets an A+.